# Adding items when a button is pressed in c# console application

Tags: c#, .net

I have been working on a small console application which has a list of items, and when a number is pressed, the relevant item should be calculated to the total (which is done).

The issue lies in how to add that items to a list view and show them in the console application. This is what i have got so far with

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace SuperMarcado
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            ShoppingCart myCart = new ShoppingCart();

            Product[] shopProducts = new Product[]
            {
                new Product("Cheese", 6, "Milk Cheese", "3/12/2016", 4),
                new Product("Bread", 2, "Grain Bread", "27/11/2016", 8),
                new Product("Ice Cream", 10, "Ice Cream", "09/11/2001", 1),
                new Product("Cookies", 100, " Chocolate Cookies", "00/00/0000", 5),
                new Product("Biscuits", 0.25f, "Vanila ", "08/01/2006", 6)
            };

            Shop shop = new Shop(shopProducts);
            shop.DisplayProducts();
            Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------------------");

            myCart.printY = Console.CursorTop;
            myCart.Display();
            ConsoleKeyInfo input;


            while ((input = Console.ReadKey(true)).Key != ConsoleKey.Escape)
            {
                if (!Char.IsDigit(input.KeyChar))
                    return;
                int index = Convert.ToInt16(input.KeyChar.ToString()) - 1;

                if (index < 1 || index > shop.products.Length)
                    return;

                myCart.AddProduct(shop.products[index]);

                shop.DecreaseAmount(shop.products[index]);

                shop.DisplayProducts();

                myCart.Display();



                int userInput = 0;
                do
                {

                    userInput = ShoppingCart();

                } while (userInput != 5);
            }

        }
        static public int ShoppingCart()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Your cart");
            Console.WriteLine();
            var result = Console.ReadLine();
            return Convert.ToInt32(result);
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: what exactly is your problem ?

Comment: How to add items and make a shopping cart like thing and display it all the time when numbers are pressed.

Comment: That's what you want it to do.  You haven't illustrated what is doing wrong or what it is not doing that you're stuck on.

Comment: do you have a tutorial maybe?

Answer (score 0):

At first, your problem is this second loop, remove it and it should work as intended

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace SuperMarcado
{
class MainClass
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        ShoppingCart myCart = new ShoppingCart();

        Product[] shopProducts = new Product[]
        {
            new Product("Cheese", 6, "Milk Cheese", "3/12/2016", 4),
            new Product("Bread", 2, "Grain Bread", "27/11/2016", 8),
            new Product("Ice Cream", 10, "Ice Cream", "09/11/2001", 1),
            new Product("Cookies", 100, " Chocolate Cookies", "00/00/0000", 5),
            new Product("Biscuits", 0.25f, "Vanila ", "08/01/2006", 6)
        };

        Shop shop = new Shop(shopProducts);
        shop.DisplayProducts();
        Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------------------");

        myCart.printY = Console.CursorTop;
        myCart.Display();
        ConsoleKeyInfo input;


        while ((input = Console.ReadKey(true)).Key != ConsoleKey.Escape)
        {
            if (!Char.IsDigit(input.KeyChar))
                return;
            int index = Convert.ToInt16(input.KeyChar.ToString()) - 1;

            if (index < 1 || index > shop.products.Length)
                return;

            myCart.AddProduct(shop.products[index]);

            shop.DecreaseAmount(shop.products[index]);

            shop.DisplayProducts();

            myCart.Display();



            //int userInput = 0;
            //do
            //{

            //    userInput = ShoppingCart();

            //} while (userInput != 5);
        }

    }

    //static public int ShoppingCart()
    //{
    //    Console.WriteLine("Your cart");
    //    Console.WriteLine();
    //    var result = Console.ReadLine();
    //    return Convert.ToInt32(result);
    //}
}
}
```

ShoppingCart Class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace SuperMarcado
{
internal class ShoppingCart
{
    internal int printY;
    internal List<Product> productList;

    public ShoppingCart()
    {
        productList = new List<Product>();
    }

    internal void Display()
    {
        if (productList.Count == 0)
            Console.WriteLine("------------------ EMPTY CART------------------ ");

        foreach (var prod in productList)
            Console.WriteLine(prod.Name + " value: " + prod.Value);
    }

    internal void AddProduct(Product product)
    {
        productList.Add(product);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: then you need to implement your method _Display_ inside your class _ShoppingCart_ with a method to iterate products added by _AddProduct_